# WPF Command bindings - how can I get to event handlers

Tags: wpf, commandbinding, routedevent, routedevents

Hi
Is there any way to choose from where XAML should use command bindings event handlers?
I added copule of command binding to my cusotm control, however functions which are resonsible for execute and can_execute are not directly in code behind but in another class. This class is derived from Canvas and I create instance of this class in XAML.

```
<s:MyCanvas  Focusable="true"  Background="Transparent" x:Name="OwnCanvas" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
```

I add command bindings this way

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" CanExecute="event handler from object OwnCanvas" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Is there any way to do that ? Or I have to transfer event handler directly to codebehind ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're gonna have to transfer the handler in codebehind as I don't think that's possible.  I could be wrong and would love to be corrected if it is possible though.

What I usually do is just define the CommandBinding in your MyCanvas class (code behind) and then reference that MyCanvas as the CommandTarget in the custom control.  Like this:

```
    public MyCanvas()
    {
        ...

        CommandBindings.Add(
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy,
                (sender, e) => {
                    // Execute Stuff
                },
                (sender, e) => {
                    e.CanExecute = true; 
                    e.Handled = true; 
                }));
        ...
    }
```

And in your custom control (given it lies within the visual tree of MyCanvas)...

```
<Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type s:MyCanvas}}}"/>
```

With your CommandTarget set up like that the Execute and CanExecute methods will be called on it.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the answer, however I need to add command bindings to entire control - I don't have any buttons on my customControl - my consist only of MyCanvas. Is there any way to make this work or I have to attach this commands to some buttons , label or sth else?